# No data is being save in `:building` column of rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dbmigrate

I have created a `valuation` table which contain

```
class CreateValuations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :valuations do |t|
      t.text :location
      t.integer :number_of_bedroom
      t.integer :number_of_bath
      t.integer :age_of_building
      t.text :other_details
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :contact_number

      t.timestamps null: false
   end
 end
```

end

And later i added a column `:building` of type text in it using `rails generate migration add_building_to_valuations building:text`. I have created a form

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for(@valuation) do |val| %>

            <%= val.label :building, "Name of Building/Builder" %>
            <%= val.text_field :building, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :location, "Location" %>
            <%= val.text_field :location, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :number_of_bedroom, "Number of Bedroom" %>
            <%= val.text_field :number_of_bedroom, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :number_of_washroom, "Number of Washroom" %>
            <%= val.text_field :number_of_bath, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :age_of_building, "Age of Building" %>
            <%= val.text_field :age_of_building, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :name, "Name" %>
            <%= val.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :email, "Email" %>
            <%= val.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.label :contact_number, "Contact Number" %>
            <%= val.text_field :contact_number, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= val.submit "Evaluate my property", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i fill all the field and submit via `Evaluate my property`, Then no data is being saved in `:building`.

I checked this using following commands 
`$ rails console`
`$ Valuation.all`

and received output are following output

```
#<Valuation id: 1, location: "Chandivali, Powai", 
number_of_bedroom: 3, number_of_bath: 3, 
age_of_building: 9, other_details: nil, name: "Shravan", 
email: "shravan.xxx@gmail.com", 
contact_number: "9876543210",created_at: "2015-11-14 09:47:26",
updated_at: "2015-11-14 09:47:26", building: nil>,
```

Comment: Is there a chance you are using strong params and you didn't update the permit to include the new `building` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your `valuation_params` Which is most likely a private function

```
private
    def valuation_params
        params.require(:valuation).permit(:building,
                 :location,
                 :number_of_bedroom, 
                 :number_of_bath, 
                 :age_of_building, 
                 :name, :email, :contact_number)
    end
end
```